# HTML frame allocation

Tags: html, html-table

I having trouble in dividing the HTML frames. I have been using the following fields in HTML:

```
<table  width=900 border="1" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="500" height="170">section1 </td>
    <td width="400" rowspan=2> section2</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td width="500" height="400" valign="left">
      <div id="response">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's creating a table, but the problem is a response element, and it is dynamically loaded.
When it loads the sizing of section1, section2 also changes. Will anybody say
alter method dividing variable size frames, which means changing the content in section1 should not affect the section 2 and similarly #response element change should not affect the sizing of section1?

Is there a new method to solve this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most browsers, tables and other elements will incrementally load so people on slower connections don't have to wait five minutes before they see something.

It should not matter if the table cells change size. You could assign a width/height to the 'response' division - that should help with it drastically changing size when the content is load.